# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Unable to share cookies among applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to share cookies among applications so that I don't have to constantly login on one app and login again in another.

This is the startup that I have on both applications

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:ConnectionString"]));
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
                = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
});
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUsers, Roles>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddScoped<LogsData>();
services.AddScoped<ApplicationUsersData>();
services.AddScoped<CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<ApplicationUsers>>();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
});

services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(KeyRingConfigurationManager.GetBasePath())
    .SetApplicationName("AppName");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AppName.Shared";
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

When I run my application, I noticed that in my Key folder, a key xml file appears. However, when I start the second application and navigate to my controller that is authorized, I get kicked back to the login page meaning I wasn't logged in. What else am I missing?

Comment: Do you have two different applications?

Comment: Yes but application 2 has references to certain components within application 1

Comment: Okay. i got some ideas from the below msdn site. it may helps you, refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Thats what I was following.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check about adding session with your services? I have tried some code regarding that and it does working fine for me.

```
    services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
```

Also add usesession() in your COnfigure() method.

```
        app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Must I use sessions for this?

Comment: As i know, session helps to save cookies for the application. Once session expired your cookies does not works.